# All of my google scripts suddenly stopped loading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am having issues with running custom formulas on google spreadsheets. Everything was working fine a couple of days ago.

- When I open Extensions --> Apps Script, it opens the correct script
- Even a basic function like the example DOUBLE function isn't working, so I don't think its an issue with my code
- Nothing is getting logged on the Execution logs
- Instead of a #NAME? error, I get a Loading... error
- The #NAME? error comes up when I try a formula that doesn't exist, as it should.

Comment: Make a copy of your sheet and see if that helps

Comment: I have tried that and many other similar solutions. Creating a new copy of my sheet. Deleting and recreating a new scripts file. Switching wifi networks. Switching browsers. Even a brand new blank sheet and following a yt tutorial won't work, and it feels like Im somehow missing a basic, crucial step.

Comment: Replace functionality with standard scripts

Comment: Provide [mcve].